# How to plot in matplotlib with values on yaxis with larger precision (or with more decimal places)?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the following list where 
`x=[1,2,3]` and multiple y-axes

```
yaxis[0] [0.33849846 0.32946841 0.33203313], yaxis[1] [0.33854376 0.32944497 0.33201127],yaxis[2] [0.33854256 0.32944559 0.33201185],yaxis[3] [0.33854259 0.32944557 0.33201184],yaxis[4] [0.33854259 0.32944557 0.33201184],yaxis[5] [0.33854259 0.32944557 0.33201184],yaxis[6] [0.33854259 0.32944557 0.33201184]
yaxis[7] [0.33854259 0.32944557 0.33201184].
```

But the plot takes only first 3 decimal paces how to make it to plot with high precision

Comment: For formatting tick lables you can use `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ticker.StrMethodFormatter`; for example, this will print 6 decimal places:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:.6f}'))
```

[image]